# Zero divisors of the ring $\mathbb F_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> What are the zero divisors of $\mathbb F_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$?

I think it is not a field, since the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb F_2$. And because the ring is finite one has to show that it has a zero divisor, is it:

$$\mathbb F_2[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle =\mathbb F_2[x]/\langle (x+1)^2\rangle $$

I'm stuck here, does the latter imply that $x^2=x=1$, so are there less than $4$ elements, otherwise I cannot find a zero divisor, can you help ?

Comment: Hint: What happens if you multiply $x+1$ with itself in this quotient?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft but is it not already zero in our ring I mean, $x^2=x=1$ implies $x+1=0$ modulo $2$ ?

Comment: Why do you think $x^2=x$?

Comment: Where do you get $x^2 = x$ from?

Comment: I think he gets $x^2 = x$ from the fact that $a^2 = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}_2$. The misconception is the belief that a polynomial and the function it defines are the same.

Comment: When you work in $\mathbb Z _2$, then $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2+0+y^2=x^2+y^2$, so in your case, $(x+1)^2=x^2+1$. The only root of this polynomial in $\mathbb Z_2$ is $x=1$.

Comment: By Fermat's Little Theorem, the polynomial $x^p$ will give the same value as $x$ for every point in the field $F_p$. These are still counted as distinct polynomials. Note that two distinct polynomials over an _infinite_ field cannot agree on every point in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that, over the field with two elements, $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$.

However, it is *false* that $x^2=x$, because $x$ is intended to be an indeterminate or, in other words, a transcendental element over the field.

You can avoid ambiguities if you try with $F[x]/\langle(x-r)^2\rangle$, where $F$ is any field and $r\in F$.

Any element of the quotient ring can be written in a unique way as $a+bx+\langle(x+1)^2\rangle$, so there are four of them
$$
0+I,\quad
x+I,\quad
1+I,\quad
1+x+I
$$
where $I=\langle(x+1)^2\rangle$; it shouldn't be difficult to do the check.

For instance, $(1+x+I)^2=0+I$. Is $x+I$ a zero divisor?

Comment: Yes I thouth too much, $x$ is an indeterminate, you're correct. to your question $(x+I)(x+1+I)=(x^2+x+I)=(x^2+1+(x-1)+I)=x+1+I$ I don't see why it should be, thanks by the way

Comment: @user1161 Consider that $(x+I)^2=1+I$

Comment: apologize but where is $0$, what you've written means that $x+I$ is self inverse

Comment: @user1161 Yes, it equals its inverse, so it can't be a zero divisor