# Use of irreducible polynomial in finite field construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

When constructing a finite field $\mathrm{GF}(p^n)$ using polynomials:

1. Why do we need to modulo an *irreducible* polynomial? What happens if this polynomial is reducible?
2. Does such an irreducible polynomial always exist? If so, is there a systematic way to find it when $n$ is large?

Comment: For 1., do some easy *examples*, like $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ to see what happens - or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944749/zero-divisors-of-the-ring-mathbb-f-2x-langle-x21-rangle). Note that $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I tried to construct GF(4) from GF(2) with x^2+1 instead of x^2+x+1. What I found when building the multiplication table was x=1, which made this GF(4) collapse into GF(2). But I couldn't explain why this happens.

Comment: As the title of the linked post suggests, we have *zero divisors* then. This is what an example shows you explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not irreducible then $k[x]/(f)$ is not an integral domain, if it is irreducible then $k[x]/(f)$ is a field. Depending on the field $k$ only some degrees of irreducible $f$ might exist, but for $k$ a finite field there are irreducible polynomials of every degrees, this is because the splitting field of $x^{q^n}-x\in k[x]$ is a field with $q^n$ elements, where $q = cardinality(k)$. There is no simple way to find some $f$ of a given large degree.